# Symfony2 Doctrine2 produce a sql wrong

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have create an entity in the way the ID is a string type.

```
class Item 
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_item", type="string", length=60)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idItem;
.....
```

When I insert the new element in form I get an error

> ERROR - Failed to create object: Acme\BasicCmsBundle\Entity\Device
>   Context: {"exception":"Object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Exception\ModelManagerException)","previous_exception_message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO  item (referente_id) VALUES (?)' with params [null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERRORE: valori null nella colonna \"id_item\" violano il vincolo non-null\nDETAIL: La riga in errore contiene (null, null)."}

The Doctrine ORM non inserts the ID in query.

I use:

- Symfony 2.7
- doctrine 2
- sonata Admin bundle
- postgresql

Comment: Can you show the code where you prepare and persist the entity? Because it looks like you're setting null on a notnull field. Also, 'identity' strategy on a string?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot add Sonata admin bundle
To create new entity I use sonata CRUD controller. I try to remove the identity strategy to see it works.

Comment: Besides that, your main problem seems to be that you're trying to persist a single value (`referente_id`) and you're sending that value empty.

Comment: Yes. The query is generated by Doctrine2. I insert the `id_item` but it is ignored when the query is generated. The `id_item` is primary key and the `referente_id` may be null. Why Doctrine ignore `id_item` insert by me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use postgres try to insert the sequence generator in your entity ;)

Example:

```
class Item 
{
/**
  * @var string
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id_item", type="string", length=60)
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
  * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="item_seq",allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
  */
private $idItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

From error message it seems `referente_id` is not set in `Item` Entity.
You should add (if You alredy do not have) `Item::setReferente()` and call it by setting proper `Referente` entity.